# Compare strings in python like the sql "like" (with "%" and "_")

Tags: python, regex, string, wildcard

I have a list in python with some strings, and I need to know witch item in the list is like "A1_8301". This "_" means that can be any char.
Is there a quick way to do that?

If I was using SQL, i just type something like "where x like "A1_8301"

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Python you'd use a regular expression:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^A1.8301$')
matches = [x for x in yourlist if pattern.match(x)]
```

This produces a list of elements that match your requirements.

- The `^` and `$` anchors are needed to prevent *substring* matches; `BA1k8301-42` should not match, for example. The `re.match()` call will only match at the start of the tested string, but using `^` makes this a little more explicit and mirrors the `$` for the end-of-string anchor nicely.
- The `_` in a SQL like is translated to `.`, meaning *match one character*.

Answer (score 5):

regular expressions are probably the way to go.  IIRC, `%` should map to `.*` and `_` should map to `.`.

```
matcher = re.compile('^A1.8301$')
list_of_string = [s for s in stringlist if matcher.match(s)]
```

Comment: Good point, although only substrings at the beginning of the string since we're using `re.match` rather than `re.search`...  In any event, I've updated.

Comment: Yeah, I added it for that reason.