# How to compare two string with some characters only in python

Tags: python, string

I have two strings to compare and the following result should return

```
s1 = 'toyota innova'
s2 = 'toyota innova 7'
if s1 like s2
   return true
```

OR

```
s1 = 'tempo traveller'
s2 = 'tempo traveller 15 str'  //or tempo traveller 17 str
if s1 like s2
    return true
```

So, how this I compare in python?
for eg.
[getmecab.com/round-trip/delhi/agra/tempo-traveller](http://www.getmecab.com/round-trip/delhi/agra/tempo-traveller)

In this it is showing that we don't find this model name but if you scroll down there is tempo traveller 12str/15str showing. so I have show these two cabs in search of tempo traveller.

Comment: See [*Compare strings in python like the sql “like” (with “%” and “_”)*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148712/compare-strings-in-python-like-the-sql-like-with-and)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `in` to check if a string is contained in an other:

```
'toyota innova' in 'toyota innova 7' # True
'tempo traveller' in 'tempo traveller 15 str' # True
```

If you only want to match the start of the string, you can use `str.startswith`:

```
'toyota innova 7'.startswith('toyota innova') # True
'tempo traveller 15 str'.startswith('tempo traveller') # True
```

Alternatively, if you only want to match the end of the string, you can use `str.endswith`

```
'test with a test'.endswith('with a test') # True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.startswith()` method.

```
if s2.startswith(s1):
    return True
```

or you may use `in` operator, as suggested by user312016

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to check `if s2 in s1` like this:

```
def my_cmp(s1, s2):
    return (s1 in s2) or (s2 in s1)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> s1 = "test1"
>>> s2 = "test1 test2"
>>>
>>> my_cmp(s1, s2)
True
>>>
>>> s3 = "test1 test2"
>>> s4 = "test1"
>>>
>>> my_cmp(s3, s4)
True
```